# react-native .babelrc changes not working

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I had an issue compiling my react native app, because of an incorrect setting in .babelrc. I removed the offending setting and ran it again in the ios simulator **react-native run-ios** but I still see the same error:

```
Unknown option:/.../.babelrc.requireDirective
```

even though I have completely removed the requiredDirective option from .babelrc.

I tried running npm cache clear, but still get the same issue.

It looks like my problem is that it is still hanging on to the old .babelrc settings.  If so, how can I go about clearing it properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try to run the packager with `--reset-cache` option?

`react-native start --reset-cache`